# Process multiple objects in Google cloud

Tags: python, hadoop, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, hadoop-streaming

I have a few hundred files(100,000) in a Google Storage Bucket. The file sizes are about 2-10MB. I need to apply a simple python function(just data transformation) on each of these files. I need to read from one bucket - transform (python function) in parallel - and store in another bucket. I am thinking of a simple Hadoop or Spark cluster to do this. I previously used concurrent threads on a single instance to do this, but I need a more robust approach. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the recently-announced [Google Cloud Dataproc](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/) (in **beta** as of 5 Oct 2015), which provides a managed Hadoop or Spark cluster for you. It is integrated with Google Cloud Storage so you can read and write data from your bucket.

You can [submit jobs](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/submit-job) via `gcloud`, the console, or via SSH to a machine in your cluster.